# Nginx rewrite a URL to another format

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I want to rewrite a URL to another URL format in NGINX configuration. Here is the configuration:-

```
    server {
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass       http://localhost:9000;
                proxy_set_header Host      $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
            location /static/ {
                alias  /var/www/test/;
                rewrite ^/static/.*/(.*)/report/(.*)$ /static_contents/$1/img/$2 break;
            }}
```

Here URL would be

```
http://example.com/static/download/some_name/report/image/3.jpeg
```

i want rewrite rule to convert above url to this format

```
http://example.com/static_contents/some_name/img/3.jpeg
```

Content location is

```
/var/www/test/static_contents/some_name/img
```

Unable to figure out the way to do this.

When i try to log i get errors as

> "alias" cannot be used in location "/static/" where URI was
>   rewritten, client:

Comment: Do you need rewrite or redirect?

Comment: http://example.com/static/download/some_name/report/image/3.jpeg needed to be redirected to http://example.com/static_contents/some_name/img/3.jpeg

Comment: You should be using the [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive rather than the [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive, which will fix the immediate problem. Not sure about your regex though, it doesn't look right either. Try: `^/static/download/(.*)/report/image/(.*)$`

Comment: i still get the  404 error. @RichardSmith